# unsigned char allocation comes nils in offset value objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, pixel, unsigned-char

I am getting the pixel colour values from touch points. I am successfully doing this but after sometimes app is giving the error( EXC_BAD_ACCESS(CODE=1,address=0x41f6864). Its memory allocation problem here is the source code for your reference.

```
- (UIColor *) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
UIColor* color = nil;

@try{

    {

    CGImageRef inImage =  drawImage.image.CGImage;

// Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
if (cgctx == NULL)
{
    return nil; /* error */

}  
size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};

// Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
// allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
// raw image data in the specified color space.
   CGContextDrawImage (cgctx, rect, inImage);


// Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
// context.
        unsigned char *data = {0};
       data=(unsigned char*) calloc(CGImageGetHeight(inImage) * CGImageGetWidth(inImage) , CGBitmapContextGetHeight(cgctx)*CGBitmapContextGetWidth(cgctx));

data= CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);






  if( data !=NULL  ) {



    //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
    //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.


      int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));

           // NSLog(@"%s111111",data);

     int alpha =  data[offset]; /////// EXC_BAD_ACCESS(CODE=1,address=0x41f6864)           

    int red = data[offset+1];
    int green = data[offset+2];
    int blue = data[offset+3];



    //NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
     color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }
// When finished, release the context
//CGImageRelease(*data);
CGContextRelease(cgctx);

// Free image data memory for the context
if (data)
{

 free(data);  
}
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
}
return color;
}
```

Comment: It would help to show the error message as well.

Comment: Have a try: `int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y-1))+round(point.x-1));`. I am not sure if `point.y` or `point.x` starts from 0, if they don't, point.x should be in the range [1, w], point.y [1, h], or they should be [0, w-1], [0, h-1] respectively.

Comment: At least try to format your code properly (as an extra benefit it will be a lot easier to spot problems yourself).

Answer (score 1):

The memory management in your code appears to be wrong:

Declare `data` and pointlessly assign a value to it:

```
unsigned char *data = {0};
```

Allocate a memory block and store a reference to it in `data` - overwriting the pointless initialisation:

```
data = (unsigned char *)calloc(CGImageGetHeight(inImage) * CGImageGetWidth(inImage), CGBitmapContextGetHeight(cgctx) * CGBitmapContextGetWidth(cgctx));
```

Now get a reference to a *different* memory block and store it in `data`, throwing away the reference to the `calloc`'ed block:

```
data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
```

Do some other stuff and then free the block you did not `calloc`:

```
free(data);
```

If you are allocating your own memory buffer you should pass it to `CGBitmapContextCreate`, however provided you are using iOS 4+ there is no need to allocate your own buffer.

As to the memory access error, you are doing no checks on the value of `point` and your calculation would appear to be producing a value of `offset` which is incorrect. Add checks on the values of `point` and `offset` and take appropriate action if they are out of bounds (you will have to decide what that should be).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The problem may cause by the `point` is out of image `rect`,so you can use

```
try{

    int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
    int alpha =  data[offset];       
    int red = data[offset+1];
    int green = data[offset+2];
    int blue = data[offset+3];



    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f)
         alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];

}catch(NSException e){

}
```

to avoid the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`